# PHP Mail is visiting links placed in body

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm sending out activation code for user sign ups but both Mail() and Pear Mail are literally visiting the links that are placed in the body when it is sent.  I've never seen this before and I'm assuming it's a PHP setting turned on that's need to be disabled.

Below is a sample, if you visit test.php it sends an email, however PHP is also reading the link in the body and visits testme.php.  That file then sends an email to me as well.  I get 2 emails visiting just test.php.  It's impossible to create an activation link right now because I keep being activated before receiving an email.

This took me literally 6 hours to realize what was happening and I'm fed up.

Code as a basic test:

**test.php:**

```
<?php
$to = 'xxxxxxx';
$subject = "From Test.php";
$body = "Thank you for registering.\n\n To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n http://xxxxx.com/testme.php\n\n Thanks\n";
$additionalheaders = "From: <XXXXXXX>\r\n";
$additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: XXXXXXX";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

echo "done";

?>
```

**testme.php:**

```
<?php
$to = 'xxxxxxx';
$subject = "From Test Me";
$body = "You shouldn't receive this";
$additionalheaders = "From: <xxxxxxx>\r\n";
$additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: xxxxxxx";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

?>
```

Any ideas what would be causing it?   Server is running PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: php is not visiting urls in an email you send. start by looking at the access logs and see what is actually hitting testme.php

Comment: The links are probably being visited by a spam or virus filter on the receiving side, or the email client. Access logs would verify this.

Comment: It seems like a regular request from my machine, though I'm not using Mozilla I'm using Chrome which seems strange.  `[14/Oct/2015:15:40:53 -0400] "GET /testme.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - -`

Comment: I assume the ip is your own. Is that timestamp when you read the mail? If anti-virus software or your email client will hit the links, you'll just have to assume on the server side that a link could be visited multiple times;  track if an email was sent in a database, and if it was, don't send it again.

Comment: If it is a user-based system, you could always require the user to log-in to do what you were doing, as well.